# Bulls and Cows game?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering

For those who aren't familiar, the game is a number guessing game, where a number is chosen (non repeating; e.g 1223 is NOT chosen) and the user makes a guess and obtains information whether the number AND digit is correct, number is correct but in a wrong digit, or the number is not contained. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulls_and_cows

(e.g number chosen => 1234, guessing 3789 will give 1 cow)

Instead of the computer choosing the number and telling the properties and player guesses, I would like to do the reverse; I type in a number and the properties - the computer gives a list of possible numbers.

Anyways, my method is:

1. Add all numbers that do not repeat itself to the arraylist
2. Delete numbers that do not satisfy the conditions.

Here is how the cow cases are done :

```
     //Case 5: property is 4 cows;
     if (property.equals("040")) {
        //delete if numbers don't appear EXACTLY 4 times
        if (contains != 4) { numbers.remove(i); }

        //removes if the digits of the number tried corresponds with the actual number (Cow!)
        else if (n.charAt(0) == first.charAt(0)) { numbers.remove(i); }
        else if (n.charAt(1) == second.charAt(0)) { numbers.remove(i); }
        else if (n.charAt(2) == third.charAt(0)) { numbers.remove(i); }
        else if (n.charAt(3) == fourth.charAt(0)) { numbers.remove(i); }
     }
```

It has worked for cows. Upon trying to implement bulls, it seems like using this sort of approach won't be possible. **How can I do a method for bulls!? Would I need to create four more arraylists and calculate for each case? Or is ArrayList not the way to go?**

For example, 1234 with 1bull would mean the number to guess is 1XXX, X2XX, XX3X or XXX4 but 
I can't use this approach as it will delete all number except the input.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this algorithm for solving -

```
String userAnswer = // ... getUserAnswer();        
if(userAnswer == null || userAnswer.equals("")
        || !userAnswer.matches("^-?\\d+$") 
            || userAnswer.split("(?<=\\G.{1})").length < 4) {
    // error    
}                

int[] secret = (int[])// ... getSecret(request);        
int[] seq = {1,2,3,4};

for(int i = 0; i < userAnswer.split("(?<=\\G.{1})").length; i++) {
    seq[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
}

int bullCount = 0;
int cowCount = 0;

for(int i = -1; ++i < secret.length;) {
  if(secret[i] == seq[i]) {
    bullCount++;
  }
}

for(int i = -1; ++i < secret.length;) {
  for(int j = -1; ++j < secret.length;) {
    if(secret[i] == seq[j] && i != j) {
      cowCount++;
    }
  }
}

String snswer = bullCount + "b" + cowCount +  "c";            
if(Arrays.equals(secret, seq))
 // win! 
else
// fail!
```

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong as if the code is 1634 and the user enters 6113, the program returns 4 cows when there is in fact 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    private static String findNumberOfCowsAndBulls(String firstString, String secondString) {

    if(firstString.equals(secondString))
        return "All Bulls:" + firstString.length();

    char[] fSArr = firstString.toCharArray();
    char[] sSArr = secondString.toCharArray();
    int countCow = 0;
    int countBull = 0;
    Map<String, Integer> fSMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> sSMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < fSArr.length; i++) {
        if(i < sSArr.length){
            if(fSArr[i] == sSArr[i]){
                countBull++;
            }
            else{
                updateMapOfCharsCount(fSMap, fSArr[i]);
                updateMapOfCharsCount(sSMap, sSArr[i]);
            }
        }
        else{  //fSArr is bigger than sSArr
            updateMapOfCharsCount(fSMap, fSArr[i]);
        }
    }

    if(fSArr.length < sSArr.length){  //fSArr is shorter than sSArr
        for(int i = fSArr.length; i < sSArr.length - fSArr.length; i++){
            updateMapOfCharsCount(sSMap, sSArr[i]);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : fSMap.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        if(sSMap.containsKey(key)){
            if(sSMap.get(key) <= fSMap.get(key))
                countCow = countCow + sSMap.get(key);
            else
                countCow = countCow + fSMap.get(key);
        }
    }

    return "countCow = " + countCow + " countBull = " + countBull;
}

private static void updateMapOfCharsCount(Map<String, Integer> fsMap, char c) {
    String key1 = String.valueOf(c);
    if (fsMap.containsKey(key1)) {
        fsMap.put(key1, fsMap.get(key1) + 1);
    } else
        fsMap.put(key1, 1);
}
```